# Submit form without page refresh (partially page refresh)

Tags: php, ajax

Index.php in HTML head:

```
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
  <script>
    // wait for the DOM to be loaded
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function
      $('#loginform').ajaxForm(function() {

        $.get("loginform.php", function(data) {
          $("#loginform1").html(data);
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

loginform.php:

```
<div id="loginform1">
<?php if(!isset($_COOKIE['login']) && $obj->checkCookie($database, $_COOKIE['login'])){ ?>
<form class="pure-form" id="loginform" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <fieldset>
        <legend style="width:500px;">Anmeldung</legend>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Benutzername">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Passwort">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Login</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<?php } else { ?>
  <form class="pure-form" id="loginform" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
      <fieldset>
          <legend style="width:500px;">Anmeldung</legend>
          <button type="submit" name="logout" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Logout</button>
      </fieldset>
  </form>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

The **loginform.php** is included in a file called **header.inc** which is included on **index.php**.

Right now the login works with ajax, the page doesn't refresh and it sets the cookies. But the login form doesn't refresh, so after logging in it doesn't display the logout button and the whole page doesn't display the content I want to display after logging in. After refreshing the page manually it displays the logout button and the content.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

      $('#loginform').submit(function() {

var fdata = $('#loginform').serialize()
            $.ajax({
                url: "login.php",//path to the page submit data
                type: 'GET',
                data: fdata,
                success: function (data) {
                    //do on success
                }

            });

       return false;

      });
    });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, remove `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"`,

You may add jquery script like,

```
$("input[name=yourbtnname]").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url:'yoururl.php',
    data:'yourdatacontenet',
    ...,
    success:function(result){
        /* show your resulted data */
        console.log(result);
    }
  });
});
```

and make your php script in `yoururl.php`

for your further insertion data

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting login information via ajax, then PHP's `header()` redirect isn't going to work. You need to refresh the page via JavaScript when login is successful.
i.e. you can run this (in loginform.php) when login is successful:

```
if($login) {
    // run this only if login is successful
    echo "<script>
        setTimeout(function(){
           window.location='index.php';
        }, 2000);
    </script>";
}
```